# Google cloud instance doesn't allow me to ssh with error: due to external disks detached?

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've had a google cloud instance for some time and I used to ssh into it without any problem. At some point I had to remove the additional disk on which I just had some files. Now it doesnàt allow me to ssh into it anymore. Can the two things be linked? The firewall is set to default and it has the rule to allow SSH from anywhere.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reboot your cloud instance. What error do you get?.

Comment: I did try to restart but nothing happens. I think it's because I deleted my hard drive before unmounting it. Now when I reboot I think it wants a key input that I don't see to skip the mounting task. I tried to connect to the serial port and it did ask to skip that task, but I don't have a login password for connecting with the serial port (strange, I'm using my ssh key anyway).

Comment: Here is a useful troubleshooting guide for ssh related problems: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors.